# JS : Remove all strings which are starting with specific character

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I have an array contains names. Some of them starting with a dot (.), and some of them have dot in the middle or elsewhere. I need to remove all names only starting with dot. I seek help for a better way in JavaScript.

```
var myarr = 'ad, ghost, hg, .hi, jk, find.jpg, dam.ark, haji, jive.pdf, .find, home, .war, .milk, raj, .ker';
var refinedArr = ??
```

Comment: You have a string. If you split on comma you have an array. Use a filter or a map to remove the strings

Comment: You should add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: `myarr` is not actually an array. It is a string. Is this actual variable or is it actually an array in your code?

Comment: Yes, it s a string, before split. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filter function and you can access the first letter of every word using item[0]. You do need to split the string first.

```js
var myarr = 'ad, ghost, hg, .hi, jk, find.jpg, dam.ark, haji, jive.pdf, .find, home, .war, .milk, raj, .ker'.split(", ");
var refinedArr = myarr.filter(function(item) {
  return item[0] != "."
});

console.log(refinedArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```js
let myarr = ['ad', 'ghost', 'hg', '.hi', 'jk'];
let res = myarr.filter(e => ! e.startsWith('.'));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: That is so lame.

Comment: Yeah, lame and sad... @mplungjan

Comment: I know it shows it in linked MDN Docs but just for completeness and quick overview, `startsWith` is not supported in IE.

Comment: All are not equal. That's why some peoples feels some questions are so irrelevant. Cheer up!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegEx [`\B\.\w+,? ?`](https://regex101.com/r/BJPbQB/2/) and replace with an empty String.

- `\B` matches a non word char
- `\.` matches a dot
- `\w+` matches one or more word char
- `,?` matches `0` or `1` `,`
- `[space]?` matches `0` or `1` `[space]`

**Demo:**

```js
const regex = /\B\.\w+,? ?/g;
const str = `ad, ghost, hg, .hi, jk, find.jpg, dam.ark, haji, jive.pdf, .find, home, .war, .milk, raj, .ker`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```